# MS SQL query to pivot in same column with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, multiple-columns

`Table1` has the list of persons who have brought the products (A,B,C)

I want to show how many person has records for each combination of products, using a SQL query.

**Please Note**:

1.The Products are not known , therefore cannot hardcode the product name, there can be 'n' number of product names in the table.

**Table1**:

```
ID  Person  Product
-------------------
1   Jannet  A
2   Jannet  B
3   Ross    A
4   Jane    C
5   Jane    B
6   Jane    A
7   Jannet  A
```

Output required:

```
Product     A   B   C
----------------------
A           0   2   1
B           2   0   1
C           1   1   0
```

Comment: explain your result? what is your RBDMS?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am using MYSQL, the result i am expecting is , I want to show the count of the no of distinct person who have each of the combination of products, eg. Jannet & Jane has product A as well as B , so under Product A & B it should show 2 since 2 people have this combination of products.

Comment: So the result will always be symmetric along the diagonal?

Comment: Yes , because we are taking person count for distinct products, like Jannet may have 2 products of A & 1 product of B and Jane has 1 product of A & 1 product of B, the total no of client for products A & B will be 2 (that is Jannet & Jane in the example above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Product ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN productx = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) A ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN productx = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) B ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN productx = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) C
FROM    ( SELECT   DISTINCT  tb.Product product ,
                    tb2.Product productx ,
                    tb3.Person
          FROM      ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                Product
                      FROM      Remsys.TABLE_1
                    ) tb
                    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                        Product
                                 FROM   Remsys.TABLE_1
                               ) tb2
                    INNER JOIN Remsys.TABLE_1 tb3
                    ON tb.Product = tb3.Product
                    INNER JOIN Remsys.TABLE_1 tb4
                    ON tb2.Product = tb4.Product
          WHERE     tb.product <> tb2.product
                    AND tb3.person = tb4.person
        ) otb
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem with this is , if there are multiple records of the same person with the same product , they too get added up. But i need the count of distinct persons who  the product combinations. For eg. In the above example if Jannet has one more record for Product A, the output should still show as 2 for A & B

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked.. But What if the products are unknown, in that case i wont be able to hardcode them in the case statements. So how do you make this work for all the different products in the table?

Comment: Use this query with dynamic sql - i.e. select a distinct of products to build the query string. Have a look at dynamic sql and if you get stuck let me know....

Comment: Yes i did use dynamic sql but i wanted to know if there was a better way to get this . But anyways thanks again !